# Android - I can't see any events in firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am sending `Log Events` to `fireBase` like bellow :

```
FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("vendor_id", 588);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("manage_price_products", bundle);
```

But I can't see any `Event` in my `console`!

[image]

Comment: For which email id did you create an account? Make sure it is a google account

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you can use the parameters provided by `FirebaseAnalytics.Param` class as defined here: [FirebaseAnalytics.Param](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param) to pass into the `bundle`. Also note that, you can use the events provided by `FirebaseAnalytics.Event` class as defined here: [FirebaseAnalytics.Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event) to pass into `logEvent`.

For example, your code would look something like,

```
irebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, 588);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ADD_TO_WISHLIST, bundle);
```

#### Regarding Custom Events:

The official [Google Support answer](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) states that:

> Google Analytics for Firebase allows you to specify 25 parameters with
> each logged event. You can then identify up to 50 total event
> parameters (40 numeric and 10 textual) for which you would like to see
> reporting by registering those parameters with their corresponding
> events. Once your custom parameters have been registered, Google
> Analytics for Firebase will display a corresponding card showing the
> data in each event detail report.

1. In the row for the event you want to add custom parameters to, click **More** > **Edit parameter reporting**.
2. In the *Enter parameter name field*, enter the name of the parameter you'd like to add.

   If a match is found, select it in the list and click **ADD**.
   If no match is found, click **ADD**, then enter the parameter name.
3. Set the *Type* field to **Text** or **Number**. For numeric parameters, set the **Unit** of **Measurement** field.
4. Click **SAVE** then click **CONFIRM**.

Then you would be able to see the Event listed.

Please note that it may take **upto 24 hours** to get your data listed and updated on the Firebase Console. Also, the Firebase Console follows **PST** timezone.

Answer (score 13):

According to this https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad,
the events are not sent immediately, but you can activate the DebugView in your device and thus you can see the events in real-time. For that, open the emulator (or keep your device connected) and run in a terminal following command

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>
```

then go to your firebase console - in DebugView. And you could see the events in real time. To disable DebugView run

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.
```

(this works only for Android)

Comment: I have used this command debug event is perfectly log but when I have pushed my release build event is not log. 
Thanks